# Workbooks.Open VBA code line in Excel ends my F8 step through and makes the macro run (as if I had tapped F5)

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't changed this code in years. Literally. I have been using it quite often. Suddenly my macro just starts running when I F8 through these steps:

```
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=TradeDirectory & TradeDate(z) & PortMnem(z) & "Transactions.csv"
    
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=TradeDirectory & FilterSheet & ".xlsx"
```

I think I may have used this code without an issue as recently as February, but at least as recently as last October. I have tried moving the text to a new workbook. No luck. I am wondering if MSFT pushed out an update and blew this up?

Comment: I highly doubt we're going to be able to reproduce this.

Comment: "my macro just starts running when I F8 through these steps" it's not clear exactly what you mean here.  What does it do when it *doesn't* run?  What behavior made you think something was wrong?